# What's concept of off-screen bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap

What's concept of off-screen bitmap , and how can we introduce this concept in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off-screen rendering is a cheap form of double-buffering, and ensures that what is displayed on-screen is always a complete image - as opposed to one that is only partially finished drawing. It involves drawing data to a canvas that is *not* visible on-screen, and only once rendering is complete is it actually presented to the user, typically by blitting it to part of the screen that *is* visible.

It can also be used as an optimisation, by blitting pixel data from off- to on-screen in order to avoid redrawing the entire bitmap.